# Spring Cloud Vault

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config, vault

I have a Spring Boot application with spring-cloud-starter-vault-config dependency, so all my secrets are externalized.
My application uses AWS IAM authentication with preconfigured role:

```
cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
      uri: http://vault.internal:8200
      authentication: AWS_IAM
      aws-iam:
        role: vault_role_for_app
        aws-path: aws
        endpoint-uri: https://sts.amazonaws.com
```

This Vault AWS auth method is configured to drop the token in case of 2 hours from creation:

```
vault auth enable aws

vault write auth/aws/role/vault_role_for_app auth_type=iam \
              bound_iam_principal_arn=arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/Launch-Role policies=vault_policy_for_app_to_read_secret max_ttl=2h
```

So, after 2 hours from start of the application I can see that the Vault token is dropped:

```
17:20:45.835 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @87308ms
***
19:20:20.616 [Spring-Cloud-Vault-1] INFO  o.s.v.a.LifecycleAwareSessionManager - Renewing token
19:20:20.675 [Spring-Cloud-Vault-1] INFO  o.s.v.a.LifecycleAwareSessionManager - Token TTL exceeded validity TTL thre
shold. Dropping token.
```

Application still works after the token was dropped, but why?
And why don't I see the new token creation in the application logs?

Comment: It might be caching..

Comment: How can I check?